# Proper template declaration and implementation

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am trying to declare template declarations for implementing a two dimensional matrix in C++. I have never used templates before, and I was requested to use them. I only need help with the proper syntax for declaration, as the friend functions and the overload with the template are confusing, and different problems, at least compared to what I'm used to.

Internal documentation is useless as usual. I'm most focused on figuring out the error with the overloaded operator, as honestly its baffled me for at least a full day.

```
class Matrix
{
      public:
      Matrix(int sizeX, int sizeY, T initValue = T());


      T &operator()(int x, int y);

     template <class Type>
     friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Matrix<type> &m);

      template <class Mtype>
     friend Matrix<Mtype> operator+(const Matrix<MType> &m1, const Matrix<Mtype>& m2);

    private:
   vector< vector<T> > data;
   int dx, dy;
}
```

```
#ifndef MATRIX_CPP
Template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int sizeX, int sizeY, T initValue){
dx = sizeX;
dy = sizeY;
initvalue = T(sizeX, sizeY);
}

T& operator()(int x, int y){
return T[x][y];
}
```

error typename 'T' does not name a type

invalid redefinition of 'Matrix::Matrix(int int, T)'

Comment: Problem is, you've been resorting to guesswork, and your code now has so many distinct problems (as well as things you've left out) that anyone trying to help you cannot give a complete solution - every time one problem is fixed, you'll find another.   That sort of thing doesn't work well in a Q&A format.   You'll be better off getting a decent text on C++, reading the relevant section (including on templates), and then restarting your exercise from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the template type T.

```
template <class T>
 class Matrix
{
public:

     Matrix(int sizeX, int sizeY, T initValue = T());
...
```

Note that template code implementation should be in header file, not in cpp.

Comment: thanks, i added the missing "template <class T>" before the class keyword